ESLint for TS and svelte no-unused-vars store reactive element
here is my eslintrc file
.eslintrc.cjs


With this configuration I'm getting warning for this cases
import {store} from '@js/stores/globalStores'

$store = 'abc'

warning
warning  'store' is defined but never used. Allowed unused vars must match /^_.*$/u          @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
